# SQL Statement Help - Select list of CustomerID, OrderDate with the most records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'll be using the [AdventureWorks Database](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4004) to illustrate my problem.

I need to show for a particular customer a list of OrderDate with the most Orders.

My intial attempt was as follows:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE CustomerID = 11300
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderDate
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

This will get us the following result:

```
CustomerID    OrderDate             Cnt
-----------   ----------                ----
11300        2003-11-22 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-01-28 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-02-18 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-02-08 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-02-15 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-03-11 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-03-24 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-03-30 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-04-28 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-05-03 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-05-17 00:00:00.000     1
11300        2004-06-18 00:00:00.000     1
...
```

Not exactly what I wanted, as the result should only show all records where Cnt = 2, like so:

```
CustomerID    OrderDate             Cnt
-----------   ----------                ----
11300        2003-11-22 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-01-28 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-02-18 00:00:00.000     2
11300        2004-02-08 00:00:00.000     2
```

I'm stuck because I can't wrap my mind around two problems:

1) A customer might have more than one OrderDate with the same Cnt value. This means I can't do something like TOP 1 to get the desired result.
2) Because the number of Orders for each customer may be different, I cannot use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE CustomerID = 11300
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderDate HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

This will work for getting the right result for this customer, but will definitely be wrong if the next customer has only one Order for a particular day.

So, either the query is impossible in this situation, or I am approaching the query in the wrong way. Any ideas on this problem is appreciated.

Also, since this will be a query in a stored procedure, any ideas on solving this in T-SQL will be acceptable.

UPDATE: Thanks to [Mehrdad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347449/sql-statement-help-select-list-of-customerid-orderdate-with-the-most-records-in#347460), I've been introduced to [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(SQL.90).aspx), and Life is Good®. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `TOP` *`n`* `WITH TIES` clause to accomplish the task:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES CustomerID, OrderDate, COUNT(*) Cnt
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE CustomerID = 11300
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderDate
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

Alternatively, you can use a *common table expression (CTE)* to solve the problem. This solution requires SQL Server 2005 or higher:

```
WITH MyTable AS (SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, COUNT(*) Cnt
                 FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                 WHERE CustomerID = 11300
                 GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderDate)
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, Cnt
FROM MyTable
WHERE Cnt = (SELECT MAX(Cnt) FROM MyTable);
```

If you're using the CTE method, make sure the previous statement is terminated by a semicolon (if it's not the first statement). It's required before a CTE expression.

Comment: I've tested this SQL, and it works fine! That final WHERE statement is the main source of my grief because I wasn't able to find a way to reference the Max(Cnt) value. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of AdventureWorks handy to test with, but could the WITH TIES clause help out? You could do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES CustomerID, OrderDate, COUNT(*) Cnt
...
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

... which should get you all the rows that match the value in your ORDER BY clause (the count).